# How to convert arrays to objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How could I rewrite this code to object javascript. Since ***Array usage is prohibed***, I can only use **objects** here. Insted of pushing values to array, I would like to push this values into objects.

```
var container = [];
document.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var  submit = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-primary");
         submit[0].addEventListener("click",add,false);
    document.getElementById("pobrisi").addEventListener("click",deleteAll,false);

    var dateElement = document.getElementById('datum');
        dateElement.valueAsDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    }
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    }
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    dateElement.setAttribute("min",today);
});

function add() {

    var title  = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var type   = document.getElementById("type").value;
    var datum  = document.getElementById("datum").value.split("-");
        datum  = datum[2]+". "+datum[1]+". "+datum[0];
    var data  = new Book(title,type,datum);

    container.push(data.add());
    display();
}

function display(data) {

    var destination = document.getElementById("list");
    var html = "";

        for(var i =0;i <container.length; i++) {
            html +="<li>"+container[i]+"</li>";
        }
        destination.innerHTML = html;
}
function deleteAll(){
    container=[];
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="";
}
```

> Wondering if is possible to write this code whitout any **array** usage.

Comment: are you allowed to use Objects like var myVar={key: value,key:value}

Comment: Yes I am allowed to use Objects, but don't know how to use then.

Comment: Have you considered learning how to use Objects?

Comment: Container is just a bunch of html which gets put into li tags.  Why not make container a string and append the li tags and what goes in them to the string.  For datum, instead of split/join you could do a string replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript Objects is a good way to go

1- define a new object:

```
var myVar = {};
```

or

```
var myVar = new Object();
```

2- usage

```
// insert a new value, it doesn't matter if the value is a string or int or even  another object
// set a new value
myVar.myFirstValue="this is my first value";
// get existing value and do what ever you want with it
var value = myVar.myFirstValue
```

Answer (score 2):

**initial remarks**

The problem here, in my estimation, is that you haven't learned the fundamentals of data abstraction yet. If you don't know how to implement an array, you probably shouldn't be depending on one quite yet. Objects and Arrays are so widespread because they're so commonly useful. However, if you don't know what a specific data type is affording you (ie, what convenience does it provide?), then it's probable you will be misusing the type

If you take the code here but techniques like this weren't covered in your class, it will be obvious that you received help from an outside source. Assuming the teacher has a curriculum organized in a sane fashion, you should be able to solve problems based on the material you've already covered.

Based on your code, it's evident you really have tried much, but why do you think that people here will come up with an answer that your teacher will accept? How are we supposed to know what you *can* use?

---

**a fun exercise nonetheless**

OK, so (we *think*) we *need* an Array, but let's pretend Arrays don't exist. If we could get this code working below, we might not exactly have an Array, but we'd have something that works *like* an array.

Most importantly, if we could get this code working below, we'd know what it takes to make a data type that can hold a dynamic number of values. Only then can we *begin* to truly appreciate what Array is doing for us.

```
// make a list
let l = list(1) // (1)

// push an item on the end
l = push(l, 2)  // (1 2)

// push another item on the end
l = push(l, 3)  // (1 2 3)

// display each item of the list
listeach(l, function (x) {
  console.log(x)
})

// should output
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

---

**runnable demo**

All we have to do is make that bit of code (above) work **without using any arrays**. I'll restrict myself even further and *only* use functions, if/else, and equality test `===`. I see these things in your code, so I'm assuming it's OK for me to use them too.

But am I supposed to believe your teacher would let you write code like this? It works, of course, but I don't think it brings you any closer to your answer

```js
var empty = function () {}

function isEmpty (x) {
  return x === empty
}

function pair (x,y) {
  return function (p) {
    return p(x,y)
  }
}

function head (p) {
  return p(function (x,y) {
    return x
  })
}

function tail (p) {
  return p(function (x,y) {
    return y
  })
}

function push (l, x) {
  if (isEmpty(l))
    return list(x)
  else
    return pair(head(l), push(tail(l), x))
}

function list (x) {
  return pair(x, empty)
}

function listeach (l, f) {
  if (isEmpty(l))
    return null
  else
    (f(head(l)), listeach(tail(l), f))
}

// make a list
let l = list(1) // (1)
// push an item on the end
l = push(l, 2)  // (1 2)
// push another item on the end
l = push(l, 3)  // (1 2 3)

// display each item of the list
listeach(l, function (x) {
  console.log(x)
})
```

---

**closing remarks**

It appears as tho you can use an Object in lieu of an Array. The accepted answer (at this time) shows a very narrow understanding of how an object could be used to solve your problem. After this contrived demonstration, are you confident that you are using Objects properly and effectively?

Do you know how to implement an object? Could you fulfill this contract (below)? What I mean by that, is could you write the functions `object`, `set`, and `get` such that the following expressions evaluated to their expected result?

In case it's not obvious, you're not allowed to use `Object` to make it happen. The whole point of the exercise is to make a *new* data type that you don't already have access to

```
m = object()                         // m

set(m, key, x)                       // m
get(m, key)                          // x

set(m, key2, y)                      // m
get(m, key2)                         // y

set(m, key3, set(object(), key4, z)) // m
get(get(m, key3), key4)              // z
```

I'll leave this as an exercise for you and I strongly encourage you to do it. I think you will learn a lot in the process and develop a deep understanding and appreciation for what higher-level data types like Array or Object give to you

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework I feel like I shouldn't solve it for you, but rather help you in the right direction.

Like Slasher mentioned you can use objects

With JavaScript object one book would look something like

```
const book = {
    title: 'my awesome title',
    type: 'novel'
};
```

- book is the object
- title is a property with a value 'my awesome title'
- type is a property with a value 'novel'

But objects can also have other objects as values. Something like

```
const BookShelf= {
    Book1: {
        Title: 'my awesome title',
        Type: 'novel'
    },
    Book2: {
        Title: 'my horrible title',
        Type: 'sci-fi'
    }
};
```

You can reference the books in the bookshelf in two ways

```
const book1 = BookShelf.Book1 // Returns the book1 object
const title1 = Book1.Title; // Get the title
const sametitle = BookShelf.Book1.Title // Returns title for book1, same as above.
```

You can also use brackets:

```
const book1 = BookShelf['Book1'];
const title1 = BookShelf['Book1']['Title];
```

You can even make new properties on a object like this:

```
const Book3 = {
    Title: 'running out of ideas'
    Type: 'memoir'
};     
BookShelf['Book3'] = Book3;
```

Now the BookShelf has a Book3 property. So your BookShelf object looks like

```
const BookShelf= {
    Book1: {
        Title: 'my awesome title',
        Type: 'novel'
    },
    Book2: {
        Title: 'my horrible title',
        Type: 'sci-fi'
    },
    Book3 = {
        Title: 'running out of ideas'
        Type: 'memoir'
    };     
};
```

That should get you started :)

Comment: You should mention that this is misuse of an object *because* arrays are not allowed – ie, *if* arrays are available, objects should *never* be used this way